# Start Bluetooth from ADB or at boot?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to start Bluetooth from ADB without user intervention?
I tried:

```
am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
```

but this require the user to press ok. And:

```
service call bluetooth 3
```

doesn't do anything.
Enabling the bluetoothd service in init.rc doesn't work either.

```
service bluetoothd /system/bin/bluetoothd -n
    class main
    socket bluetooth stream 660 bluetooth bluetooth
    socket dbus_bluetooth stream 660 bluetooth bluetooth
    # init.rc does not yet support applying capabilities, so run as root and
    # let bluetoothd drop uid to bluetooth with the right linux capabilities
    group bluetooth net_bt_admin misc
    enabled
```

And I would prefer a command from ADB. (If anyone is wondering I need it for FCC testing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it works for you, an app can easily change the bluetooth state. The code is very simple, I'm sure you're familiar with it:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable()
```

This could be a "headless" application with a service only that listens for a specific intent. You could install it and then broadcast the activator intent.

If you want the application to not appear in the app "drawer" (only in the Settings->Apps) then remove the launcher and main intent filters from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. That is, delete these:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

From this time on you can start the app/service with the intent you define for it in the manifest file. For example, you can create and register an intent filter for the service with the action `com.company.service.bluetooth.ON` and start it with the adb command:

```
am startservice -a com.company.service.bluetooth.ON
```

There doesn't seem to be any other way to do it if the phone is not rooted. If rooted, the `service call bluetooth 3` should work.

A working solution is described in this tutorial: [How to launch an Android app from adb - And toggle bluetooth](http://hyperlogos.org/blog/drink/How-launch-Android-app-adb-And-toggle-bluetooth). They use this app: [Bluetooth On/Off Toggle App.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ne.neko.freewing.BluetoothOnOff)

Comment: Yes, I thought about making an app for this as a last resort (A BluetoothON app and a BluetoothOFF app). Is it possible to hide an app from the app drawer (We're on 4.1.2)? And then use "adb shell am start" to start it.

Answer (score 4):

On a rooted device

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 8
```

works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually seems to need a rooted device

Comment: @raphinesse yes i know, that is why the first line in my answer is " On a rooted device"